# Proper way to use platform specific separators in cmake

Tags: cmake, cross-platform

I wonder if there is a better solution to my problem. I am working on a platform independent software project and want to add python-based unittests to cmake. The issue that I encountered now is that when configuring the ctest tests and setting up the correct PYTHONPATH environment variable for running my test, I end up with a lot of boilerplate code for each test:

```
add_test(my_awesome_test ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} my_awesome_test.py)

if("${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM}" MATCHES ".*Windows.*")
  set_tests_properties(my_awesome_test PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "PYTHONPATH=somepath\;anotherpath")
else() # e.g. Linux
  set_tests_properties(my_awesome_test PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "PYTHONPATH=somepath:anotherpath")
endif()

# more tests like this after this...
```

The problem here is the branching, that is required only because of the platform dependent list separators.

**Is there some neater way to accomplish this?**

**Is there a constant which specifies the platform separator or a function that allows me to construct these lists?**

---

If there is no "proper" answer, I also wanted to share my obvious, but not-so-nice solution:

```
if("${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM}" MATCHES ".*Windows.*")
  set(SEP "\\;")
else() # e.g. Linux
  set(SEP ":")
endif()

add_test(my_awesome_test ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} my_awesome_test.py)
set_tests_properties(my_awesome_test PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "PYTHONPATH=somepath${SEP}anotherpath")

# more tests like this after this...
```

On Windows the ";" must be double escaped because otherwise it it is substituted later in the add_test line as a single ";" again, which is then in turn interpreted as the cmake-list separator leading to wrong results. However, having cmake report which character should be used as list separator would still be nicer...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `file(TO_NATIVE_PATH ...` does not convert `;` to `:` on Unix platforms. I think the easiest way is therefore something like this:

```
set(PATH "/usr/bin" "/bin")

if (UNIX)
  string(REPLACE ";" ":" PATH "${PATH}")
endif()
```

This works because CMake lists are really `;`-separated strings, so on Windows you can use them for path lists as-is. It won't work for paths containing `;` or `:` but that will trip up 99% of Unix software anyway so I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the file function as follow:

```
file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "<path>" <variable>)
file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "<path>" <variable>)
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/file.html

Comment: Unfortunately `file(TO_NATIVE_PATH...` is broken - it will *not* convert a `;`-separated CMake list to a `:`-separated path on Unix, so this is not really a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may define function/macro which transforms some choosen separator into platform-specific one. E.g., function below transforms CMake list into platform-specific path list:

```
function(to_path_list var path1)
    if("${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM}" MATCHES ".*Windows.*")
        set(sep "\\;")
    else()
        set(sep ":")
    endif()
    set(result "${path1}") # First element doesn't require separator at all...
    foreach(path ${ARGN})
        set(result "${result}${sep}${path}") # .. but other elements do.
    endforeach()
    set(${var} "${result}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

Usage:

```
to_path_list(pythonpath "somepath" "anotherpath")
set_tests_properties(my_awesome_test PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "PYTHONPATH=${pythonpath}")
```

Comment: In the end this is more of less the same solution that I found, but it is a good idea to put everything into a function to automate building the string! I will leave the post open though and wait if somebody ever drops by and posts a CMake-based answer. 

For now it just seems that it is not supported by the language itself. A lot of different OpenSource projects had similar problems - if you google there are a lot of related bug trackers referring to this issue. So lets just see what the future brings..